# Toggle player controls boolean boolean with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, boolean, toggle

Trying to toggle `BV.getPlayer().muted(true);` boolean value with a mute icon with javascript. Before any abuse and negative votes come flying - I have taken a small online course for JS in my spare time but I am still very very much amateur - html, css and php are more my forte.

Here is what I have:

`<button class="mute"><i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i></button>
 <button class="mute" style="visibility: hidden;"><i class="fa fa-volume-down"></i></button>`

```
<script >
    $(function() {
        var BV = new $.BigVideo();
        BV.init();
        if (Modernizr.touch) {
            BV.show('css/bigvideo.png');
        } else {
            BV.show('vid/one.mp4');
            BV.getPlayer().play();
        }
    });
$(".mute").click(function() {
    // toggle function goes here I believe
});
</script>
```

This script is the `BigVideo.js` based on `video.js` jQuery script.
The mute function is as follows:
`BV.getPlayer().muted(true)`

Can someone please help me to finish this? It needs to toggle true and false and also change the button i class from `fa-volume-up` to `fa-volume-down`.

Although this is a simple task for an experience head of js, it is not for me. I have searched StackOverflow, google and even gone back into my online course for answers. I did not stumble across it, and after a few hours of trial and error I am asking for help. I hope to take the answers and learn from them for future.

Answer (score 1):

If you can freely use `JQuery` take a look at [toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) is exactly what you need.

But if you want to practice **Javascript**

To change all classes for an element:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "MyClass";
```

To add an additional class to an element:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className += " MyClass";
```

To remove a class from an element:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className =
    document.getElementById("MyElement").className.replace
    ( /(?:^|\s)MyClass(?!\S)/g , '' )
```

Comment: Great! Thank you... how would I apply `toggle()` to `BV.getPlayer().muted(true)`? I know how to toggle icons now though